# How to make your own coin on the ADA Cardano Network?

Tags: ada, coin

Is there any way to start your own coin in ADA Cardano Network?

I just googled the idea but no suggestions about Cardano. Any advice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need to use the Cardano CLI. It's technical and a programming background is helpful but not required. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VfgkSoVCQpQ) is a walk through video.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @xanadont's answer, you can also use [cardmintano](https://github.com/ElGatoLoco/cardmintano) if you prefer a graphical user experience. It's being actively updated (most recent commit was ~2 weeks ago).

Answer (score 5):

The Daedalus team is working to have this ability using the Daedalus Wallet GUI.

Answer (score 1):

We also have some step-by-step instructions here: https://input-output-hk.github.io/offchain-metadata-tools/

Feel free to raise issues here: https://github.com/input-output-hk/offchain-metadata-tools/issues

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays there are websites that provide an easy way to create Cardano Native Assets in just a few clicks.

Examples

- https://cardano-native-token.com/
- https://minterr.io/mint-cardano-tokens/